# Alamofire POST encoding issue

Tags: swift, post, alamofire

I'm trying to login to a web service as follows:

```
func Login(completionHandler:@escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
        let url = MyUrl
        let parameters: Parameters = [
            "Password":password,
            "StayLoggedIn":NSNumber(value: true),
            "UserName":username
        ]

        var headers:HTTPHeaders = commonHeaders()
        headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json;charset=UTF-8"

        Alamofire.request(url, method:.post, parameters:parameters, headers:headers).responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                debugPrint(response)

            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }

        }
    }
```

Somehow, the server returns a 501 error. 
I'm in the process of rewriting an Obj-c app in Swift, and replacing NSURLSessions with Alamofire into the bargain.

What I see in my working obj-c app, is that the headers sent to the server contain

```
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

As you can see, I explicitly add this header to my request, but somehow, it is not sent to the server.

What I also see, is that my login credentials are not sent to the server.

So, I guess my question is: how do I tell Alamofire to use the correct encoding/content type?

Answer (score 0):

try this encoding `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `application/json;charset=UTF-8`

Comment: Unfortunately, that has the same, unwanted result:  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" doesn't arrive at the server, nor does the login data